# How can I display YouTube search results for a string of words in HTML/JS?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

I have a JS function, ShowResults, that pushes a set of text input field values into an array and then converts it to a string:

```js
function showResults(myQuestions, quizContainer, resultsContainer){
  var answerContainers = quizContainer.querySelectorAll('.answers');

  var toSearch = [];
  
  for(var i=0; i <= myQuestions.length-1; i++){
     toSearch.push(answerContainers[i].querySelector('input[name="a'+i+'"]').value);
  }
  toSearch = JSON.stringify(toSearch);
}
```

Now what I need to do is run a YouTube search on the contents of toSearch (minus the square brackets and commas) and display the results.

So far I've found code to create a search feature that displays results in a new page:

```html
<form action="http://www.youtube.com/results" method="get" target="_blank">
<input name="search_query" type="text" maxlength="128" />
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

However, this doesn't fit my requirements for the following reasons:

1. I need the search to be carried out automatically on calling showResults (no submit button).
2. I need to use predefined values (the contents of toSearch) rather than ask the user to input a search term.
3. This isn't as essential as the first two points, but I'd like the results to appear on the same web page if possible.
4. This is again not essential and probably harder to execute, but I'd prefer if the contents of toString didn't display in the YouTube search box on searching.

I haven't worked with YouTube API before, so I'd very much appreciate any help on how to go about this.

Comment: About the point # 1: how you call `showResults` function without button? - I can't test right now, but, as I understand your question, you want to search on Youtube, but, the results shown in your page? - if so, consider use YouTube Data API and read the documentation about YouTube Data API.

Comment: I have a button to call showResults function, but I don't want to use a second button to carry out the search after calling showResults. Thanks for the tip about YouTube Data API, I'm looking into it.